# Coindesk API React port to Gatsbyjs won't build locally or on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

After finishing a Reactjs Coindesk API tutorial I ported it over to Gatsbyjs and it works in Gatsby Develop, but it will not build locally or on Netlify.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly whats causing it without the error or the code.

With that said, in most cases I've seen where gatsby apps are working in develop but not building, it has to do with calling browser global variables like `Window` or `Document`.

The easy fix for that is doing a check before calling any of those methods:

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
    // do something with Window
}
```

You can also use useEffect or a lifecycle method that only triggers at runtime.

If a module you are pulling in is the culprit, or if browser globals aren't related to the issue you are experiencing, there are some tips for debugging/fixing that in the docs here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/